# How to filter between dates but keep duplicates that aren't included in the time period?

Tags: r, date

I have a have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("09081997", "13122006", "09081997", "22031969", "09081997"),
                   date1 = c("2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-21", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-15"))
```

There are duplicated numbers in "group" variable. For example, I need to filter between the dates "2021-08-01" to "2021-08-31". By doing that, I would "delete" the last two numbers from "group", but I need to keep all duplicates, even if they're not between the time period I want to filter. I'd need to keep all "09081997" registers. At least one of the duplicates would have to be in the time period.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this will work. I created an auxiliary variable counting by group, and only applied the filter for dates of groups that appear only one time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("date"),.fns = ymd)) %>% 
  add_count(group) %>% 
  filter(!(n == 1 & (date1 >= ymd("2021-08-01") & date2 <= ymd("2021-08-31"))))

     group      date1      date2 n
1 09081997 2021-08-09 2021-08-31 3
2 09081997 2021-08-21 2021-08-29 3
3 22031969 2021-07-19 2021-07-20 1
4 09081997 2021-07-15 2021-07-19 3
```

I am just unsure how date1 and date2 are supposed to be filtered.

Comment: For it to be filtered, at least one row from "group" needs to be included in the time period. I tried using the code you posted but it also filters the ones that aren't in the period. For example, "22031969" would have to be deleted and "13122006" should've been kept in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`, you could groupwise `grepl` for `'2021-08'` `pat`tern and check if it occurs `any`where. Since `date*` columns are character we get "false" booleans, but we can easily turn the `mode` to `"logical"`. Finally we check if the `rowSums` of the boolean are greater than zero, i.e. if any of the two dates in that row falls in `'2021-08'`, which yields the desired boolean vector to subset the data frame.

```
data[with(data, ave(cbind(date1, date2), group, FUN=\(x) any(grepl(x, pat='2021-08')))) |> 
       `mode<-`('logical') |> rowSums() |> base::`>`(0), ]
#      group      date1      date2
# 1 09081997 2021-08-09 2021-08-31
# 2 13122006 2021-08-10 2021-08-22
# 3 09081997 2021-08-21 2021-08-29
# 5 09081997 2021-07-15 2021-07-19
```

If you just have one date column, this simplifies to

```
data1[with(data1, as.logical(ave(date1, group, FUN=\(x) any(grepl(x, pat='2021-08'))))), ]
#      group      date1
# 1 09081997 2021-08-09
# 2 13122006 2021-08-10
# 3 09081997 2021-08-21
# 5 09081997 2021-07-15
```

**Update:** If you have a time period that is more complicated e.g. overlaps a month, we can use a comparison instead of the `grepl`:

```
data1[with(data1, as.logical(ave(date1, group, FUN=\(x) any(
  x >= "2021-03-08" | x <= "2021-06-04"
)))), ]
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(group = c("09081997", "13122006", "09081997", 
"22031969", "09081997"), date1 = c("2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", 
"2021-08-21", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-15"), date2 = c("2021-08-31", 
"2021-08-22", "2021-08-29", "2021-07-20", "2021-07-19")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

data1 <- data[1:2]
```

Comment: I didn't work for me, but I edited the post. I would only have to use date1, not both of them.

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos In this case it's simpler, please see update.

Comment: it worked, thanks! Is there any way I can do that but with time periods with different months, like one that starts in "2021-03-08" and ends in "2021-06-04"?

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos In this case, we may replace the `grepl` with a comparison. Please see update.

Comment: it doesn't work. With my real data, it should be around 300 obs after filtering but when I try your code it gets over 8k obs. I should be able to keep all single obs that are in the time period and, if any of the duplicates are in the time period, I have to keep all of the duplicates. I don't know if that makes sense, but the real data is about hospitalization and each group is the id of the pacient, some of them have more than 1 hospitalization, so they're clustered by "group".

Comment: + what I need is each hospitalization of the period like one that starts in "2021-03-08" and ends in "2021-06-04", for example, and if the patient has more than one hospitalization, I need all of the registers, even if they're not in the time period, BUT at least one of the patient id clusters must be in the time period.

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos Sorry you lost me. I think you should make a better example that covers your requirements.